# Computing the median over both rows and columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, rows, median

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Group1 | Group2 | Score1 | Score2 
-------|--------|--------|--------
   A   |    1   |   10   |   11   
   A   |    2   |   13   |   14  
   B   |    1   |    4   |    7   
   B   |    2   |    9   |   12  
   A   |    1   |    5   |   11   
   B   |    2   |    9   |   13  
   A   |    2   |    7   |    9  
   B   |    1   |    7   |   10
```

What I need is to create a new variable, which gives me the median value for each subgroup combination, something like

```
Group1 | Group2 | Score1 | Score2 | Median
-------|--------|--------|--------|-------
   A   |    1   |   10   |   11   |  10.5
   A   |    2   |   13   |   14   |  11.5
   B   |    1   |    4   |    7   |   7.0
   B   |    2   |    9   |   12   |  10.5
   A   |    1   |    5   |   11   |  10.5 
   B   |    2   |    9   |   13   |  10.5
   A   |    2   |    7   |    9   |  11.5
   B   |    1   |    7   |   10   |   7.0
```

(My median computation by hand could be wrong, but I think the point has been made).

I tried using the aggregate function like:

```
MedianAggregate <- aggregate(df[,45:47],
                             by = list(df$provider, df$field),
                             FUN = median)
```

What I get, instead of what I want, is something that looks like:

```
Group1 | Group2 | Score1 | Score2 
-------|--------|--------|--------
   A   |    1   |   7.5  |   11  
   A   |    2   |   10   |   11.5   
   B   |    1   |   5.5  |   8.5  
   B   |    2   |    9   |   12.5
```

basically what I need is to get the same output I would get if I would apply the median function to three rows in a matrix, rather than a dataframe, for each combination of subgroup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question, can you add a little bit more details?

Comment: I just modified it, hopefully making it more clear. I am very sorry for my awful way of explaining what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, if I understood correctly:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Group1","Group2"))
df2 %>% group_by(Group1, Group2) %>% summarise(median = median(value)) %>% merge(df, by = c("Group1","Group2"))
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! I had no idea such a function like melt existed. Thank you so much :-))

Comment: You can move from wide to long format using the reshape package (melt: you go from wide to long, i.e. multiple variables into one value column and one variable column ; cast : you go from long to wide, i.e. one variable and one value column to as many column as types of variable in your variable column). I hope I'm clear enough!

Comment: Completely clear! I know how to do these things in Stata, but moving to R I'm still learning!